# Does Visual Studio require Font Page Server Extensions to "Open Web site"?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5

I've finally installed a new server for the company's internal web services, running windows server 2012, and after some struggling I've managed to deploy web sites onto it using Visual Studio 2012. (Using both FTP and Web Deploy).

However, I'm not able to open these site's for changes afterwards....
On the old web-server running windows server 2008, I've opened the web sites using "Open Web site.../ Remote Web site" but on the server I get an error message which ends by saying "The web server does not appear to have Front Page Server Extensions installed".

Am I missing something here, or do I have to install and configure FPSE on the server? And where do I find the proper version?

Comment: Questions with more neutral wording usually receive better responses.

Comment: Sites with code are typically built as Web Applications, not Web Sites. Web Sites is the *pre-2005* type of project that does [require FPSE to open from a remote IIS ONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9d9ats98.aspx). Web Site project are [NOT RECOMMENDED](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx). While you can use a network share or FTP to open the site, the best solution is to create a Web Application project instead of a Web Site.

Comment: Also, you should *NOT* modify web sites directly on the production server. Changes should be made on a development machine and published to the production web server when finished. The Publish functionality in Web projects makes this trivial

Comment: Thanks, I know that changes made directly on the production server is not considered good programming behavior. But this being internal site's with low critical character, I've found it the fastest way to apply changes. As well as I'm then able to verify immediately that all server components works as intended. 
But I'll check out the Web Application way. Have for years just kept on going steady as before with these web solutions. Time to learn something new :-)